# Using Tonelli to integrate over $\{ |x + y| < 1, |x - y| < 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I wish to integrate the function $\exp(x-y)$ over the set $$\{ (x,y) \ | \ | x + y | < 1, | x - y | < 1\}.$$
Now, I can draw this set, and use this to get my integration bounds, and then it's just calculating integrals, but I have no idea how to formalize an answer to this question. How can I derive the integration bounds without drawing stuff, so that the procedure is actually explained rather than a "hey, look at this pretty picture over here"?

Comment: "Look at this picture over here" can be rewritten as "Let us consider the visual interpretation of the intersection points that define our integration bounds".

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is increasing in $x$ and decreasing in $y$, it is clear that on
$$E =\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 :  | x + y | < 1, | x - y | < 1\}, $$
we have $\sup_{(x,y)\in E}f(x,y) =f(1,0) = e^{1-0}=e$. Therefore
$$\iint\limits_E f(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y)\leqslant \iint\limits_E e\ \mathsf d(x\times y) = e\mu(E)<\infty.  $$
This justifies the use of Tonelli's theorem to compute the double integral as either of the iterated integrals
$$\int\mathsf dx\int f(x,y)\ \mathsf dy = \int \mathsf dy\int f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx. $$